# Time limit exceeded for contest code written in Python

Tags: python

I wrote some code for a contest in python. The test case limit is 1 <= n <= 10^9.

```
n=input("")
sum=0
for i in range(0,n):
   s=input("")
   sum=sum^s
print sum
```

It shows an error of time limit exceeded, but when I did the same in C, it worked fine. My C code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
long long int a;
int ex=0,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 scanf("%lld",&a);
 ex=ex^a;
  }
printf("%d\n",ex);
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain this difference?

Comment: What were the inputs? When you run it locally for `10^9` inputs how long does each version take?

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to accomplish.  Testing the speed of bitwise XOR or the bandwidth of taking input from `stdin`?  What does it mean to have "time limit exceeded"?  It looks like the execution time is IO bound, and most time is spent on the inner `input()` or `scanf()`.

Comment: In general, C code will be a lot faster than python code, because C is compiled to machine and python is compiled to byte codes that are executed by the python virtual machine.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, and `range(0, n)` as well as `intr^str` will raise `TypeError`. Maybe this causes the timeout?

Comment: @jojonas `input()` returns a Python object by `eval()`ing the input.  It's evil and should be avoided anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I tested in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), where it returns a string. For [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), you're right, it's equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a very simple and powerful language, but it is slow as compared to C language for a variety of reasons like:
1.It is dynamically typed
2.It is interpreted rather than compiled
3.Some of its memory access models are inefficient.

So some of the Python programs may be as slow as 20 times than a similar C program.

Comment: Technically, the code is compiled into bytecode and run on a virtual machine.

Comment: This may not be the problem at all.  Looking at the code, it is very likely that the bottleneck is the inner `input()` (Python) and `scanf()` (C), either of which *waits for input*.  It is this wait and read (both likely super slow) that limits the execution time of either program.